# Schedule job every 5 seconds in Android app

Tags: android

I want to update a list every 5 second. Is it possible to achieve this using JobScheduler API. From docs I came to know we should use JobScheduler instead of AlarmManager for scheduling any job. What are the limitations of JobScheduler in Android Oreo?

Comment: The minimum interval for a Job is 15 minutes.

Comment: are there  other ways to achieve it ?

Comment: use a `Handler` for such intervals

Comment: Specifically, a Handler inside of a Service, if you need it to run in the background.

Comment: Does handler work perfectly in android Oreo as well??

Comment: `Handler` is a key component in android platform - it has to work

Comment: thanks...it will try it